# The letters A, E, I, P, Q, and R are arranged in a circle. Find the probability that at least 2 vowels are next to one another

Tags: probability, permutations

This isn't homework, but could someone please give an explanation and answer to this question. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The only way NO vowels can be next to each other is if the sequence alternates between vowels and consonants.

Comment: Alright, would the answer be something along the lines of:

5!-(3!*2!)/5!
?

Comment: I think you are missing a bracket there for your expression to make sense probabilistically.

Comment: I think I arrived at the answer: 1-(3!*2!/5!)